# Why doesn't the preventDefault function work always?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, preventdefault

I'm trying to create a quiz with PHP and Javascript.

After a user clicked for an answer, an ajax request starts and the result is been given in the response. If it was true, the clicked button gets a 'success' class and if false, a 'wrong' class.

After this the buttons are disabled and the user can click to the next question.
But the problem is, that after one or two questions, the javascript function doesn't work and the default action of the form is being called.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Get the form.
 var form = $('#bilderquiz');

 // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
 $(form).submit(function(e) {
  // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
  

  // Serialize the form data.
  var formData = $(form).serialize();

  // Submit the form using AJAX.
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
   , async: false
  })
  .done(function(response) {
   
   var submittedAnswer = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]");
   var allAnswers = document.querySelectorAll( ".answerButton" );
   
   alert(response);
   
   if(response == 'trueAnswer'){
    submittedAnswer.removeClass('wrongAnswer');
    submittedAnswer.addClass('trueAnswer');
    $(".answerButton").attr('disabled', true);
   } else{
    submittedAnswer.removeClass('trueAnswer');
    submittedAnswer.addClass('wrongAnswer');
    $(".answerButton").attr('disabled', true);
   }
  })
  .fail(function(data) {

   // Set the message text.
   if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
   } else {
    $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
   }
  });

 });
 
});

function setClicked(input){
 $(input).parents("form").removeAttr("clicked");
 $(input).attr("clicked", "true");
}
```

```html
<div class="answerChar">A</div>
              <form id="bilderquiz" action="includes/functions.php" method="post">
                <button class="answerButton" type="submit" id="selection" name="selection" value="0" onclick="setClicked(this)">
                  <?php echo $questionData['answerButtons'][0] ;?>
                </button>
              </form>   
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="answerChar">B</div>
              <form id="bilderquiz" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <button class="answerButton" type="submit" id="selection" name="selection" value="1" onclick="setClicked(this)">
                  <?php echo $questionData['answerButtons'][1];?>
                </button>
              </form> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="answerChar">C</div>
              <form id="bilderquiz" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <button class="answerButton" type="submit" id="selection" name="selection" value="2" onclick="setClicked(this)">
                  <?php echo $questionData['answerButtons'][2];?>
                </button>
              </form> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="answerChar">D</div>
              <form id="bilderquiz" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <button class="answerButton" type="submit" id="selection" name="selection" value="3" onclick="setClicked(this)">
                  <?php echo $questionData['answerButtons'][3];?>
                </button>
              </form> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form id="bilderquiz" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
              <button class="submitButton" type="submit" id="selection" name="selection" value="4" onclick="setClicked(this)">Nächste Frage</button>
            </form> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

My second problem is, that this lines also doesn't work:

```js
submittedAnswer.removeClass('wrongAnswer');
submittedAnswer.addClass('trueAnswer');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms need unique IDs, right now they are all id="bilderquiz"
Or you could use classes.

The php:

```
<form class="capture-me">...</form>
<form class="capture-me">...</form>
```

The JS:

```
$('form.capture-me').on('submit',function(e){ .....
```